# Define requirejs module including all files in folder

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I use the `text` plugin of `require.js` to include some html templates as follows:

```
define([
    'text!/assets/templates/home/myApp.templates.home.home-pane.html',
    'text!/assets/templates/nav/myApp.templates.nav.top-navbar.html',
    'text!/assets/templates/shared/myApp.templates.shared.layout.html',
    ...
], function (HomeTmpl, TopNavbarTmpl, SharedLayoutTmpl, RegisterVerticalTmpl, LoginVerticalTmpl, ThingListItemTmpl, ThingSearchTmpl, TestTestTmpl) {

    var allHtml = function () {
        return HomeTmpl + TopNavbarTmpl + SharedLayoutTmpl + RegisterVerticalTmpl + LoginVerticalTmpl + ThingListItemTmpl + ThingSearchTmpl + TestTestTmpl;
    }

    return {
        All: allHtml,
        HomeTmpl: HomeTmpl,
        TopNavbarTmpl: TopNavbarTmpl,
        ...
    }
});
```

I really have no need to retain references to each template (even though I am doing so right now); I really just need to dump all of the templates into my `head`.

This way of doing things is cumbersome because it requires me, no pun intended, to add a reference for every new template html file.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
define(['text!/assets/templates/*'], function(Templates) { return Templates; });
```

Is it possible to do this? And if so, what is the syntax for including and stringing all the included files together as one big reference?

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea cuz if new files appear in templates folder which are not supposed to be in `head`, new issues will occur.

Comment: @mms27 good point, it wouldn't even be worth it to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RequireJS doesn't support this because it's not (always) possible to get a directory listing from a remote server. What you want is a build tool like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

For example, with the [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) task, you could use this configuration to concat all your templates to a single file (that you then include using RequireJS):

```
concat: {
    templates: {
      src: ['assets/templates/*'],
      dest: 'templates.html'
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear, but I needed to rule it out before resorting to integrating it in a build process.